# Can't edit Magento 1.9 product after import. Only showing sidebar

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, import, catalog

So i've been tasked with added another variant into our current magento export sheet. After taking one of the products as a test item and making sure all fields and areas were successfully filled i took it to magento to the import tab and got the all clear. However since this alteration to the product, i cannot access anything except the sidebar.

[image: Printscreen of Product Edit Screen]

I've looked over the csv and can't find any fault in any empty cells and i'm pretty sure i've filled it out correctly.

The example csv itself can be checked [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7jqxwkn07o4sle/testexample.csv?dl=0)

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know. I'll be playing with this for the next little while to figure out whats gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moral of the story: Check your fields. After a lot of trial and error i discovered that the reason for the error was because the Attribute set i had editted to contain the "color" attribute was NOT the correct set. There was in fact a secondary set called "Products" as opposed to "Default" which i was making changes to.

The more you know.